# Postgres - show 'present' or 'current' in date stamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have a table called `links` that shows the date-range that two people have been together (i.e. married). Here is an example of 2 rows:

```
id  association_left  association_right  dateFrom    dateTo
1   Dad               Mom                2010-02-13  2011-01-15
2   Dad               Mom                2012-04-17  2015-11-28
```

So here we see that the Dad and Mom were together for 2 different periods of time.

But I'm wondering: is there a way to show that the Dad and Mom are *currently* together? Something like:

```
id  association_left  association_right   dateFrom       dateTo
3   Dad               Mom                 2016-02-09     present
```

And if not, what would be an effective way to show if two people are *currently* together?

Comment: This being the year 2018, "Dad" and "Mom" are *not* together.  Hence, I do not understand your question.  On second thought, you might just want the `dateTo` to be `NULL`.

Comment: Oh that's an interesting idea. Maybe I'll just use *null*.

Comment: Typically people use `null` for this. In Postgres I would use `infinity` instead to mark something that has currently no known end date

Comment: Oh that is neat. `infinity` does seem like a better fit than `null`. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to use `infinity` as the upper limit for a time range that extends into the future.

`NULL`, which means “unknown”, is not the best representation for that, because that way you cannot disambiguate between “unknown date” and “a data somewhere in the future”.

Moreover, if you use `infinity`, your queries will become simpler and hence more efficient. Compare:

```
... WHERE adate >= datefrom AND (dateto IS NULL OR adate <= dateto)
```

and

```
... WHERE adate BETWEEN datefrom AND dateto
```

The second expression can use indexes much better.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are asking if there is no dateTo then   assume they are currently together

keep the dateTo column  null and use coalesce(dateTo,current_date)